# Hp DL360 G8 fans noise after PCI (GPU) installation

Tags: hp-proliant, fan

i have a problem After Install a Graphic Card in my Server
When i USE PCI slot my Server fans increase to 40%
and when i Get off Graphic card They return Normal (19%)

I Use This Server as Home Workstation and It is important not to make noise

ILO 4 Version: 2.7
Bios Last Update

What Can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by 3rd Party hardware which often couldn´t be correclty monitored by the HP internals (e.g. the ILO board). Therefore the fan kicks in in order to prevent an overheating. This issue is the case since a very long time.

For the ILO4 board you might wish to check out a custom ILO4 Firmware, which might help. Check here for more details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Keyz-9HNr7Q

Answer (score 0):

If noise is an issue, get a workstation instead of a server. Servers are performance optimised, not noise optimised. If you want to reduce the fan noise, look into replacing the fans with noctua's server fan offering, and also if you not worried about performance or heat issues, look into reducing fan curve within the operating system, or using IPMI.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a workstation, -1 for suggesting alternative fans without minding their specs